# How to map a JSON response with different indexes

Tags: json, react-native

I'm tryin to map a JSON response from API with different indexes in react-native.

This is the JSON RESPONSE stored in state modules and I wanted to get the label value inside of every modules.

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "Accounts": {
            "label": "Accounts",
            "access": [
                "access",
                "delete",
                "edit",
                "export",
                "import",
                "list",
                "massupdate",
                "view"
            ]
        },
        "AM_ProjectTemplates": {
            "label": "Projects - Templates",
            "access": [
                "access",
                "delete",
                "edit",
                "export",
                "import",
                "list",
                "massupdate",
                "view"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using this code

```
this.state.modules.map(item=> {
  return item.label
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an array of label values then:

```
Object.entries(this.state.modules.attributes).map(([k, v]) => v.label);
```

Comment: hi @AE0011 what if the JSON have only 1 record. how can I access and display it?

Comment: Hi @DawnSeeker can you show me an example of that JSON?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.values`.

```
Object.values(this.state.modules.attributes).map(a => a.label);
```